# Change Image on Hover with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am so befuddled. I am trying do something seemingly so simple but failing miserably. I'd like to have the image "b.png" change to "c.png." Can you find where I went wrong?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <img src="b.png" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.main:hover {
    background-image: url('c.png');
}
```

Comment: Your CSS is working, but the bg image is behind the other image...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `<div class="main">` *is* getting `c.png` as its background – you just can't see it behind the `<img src="b.png">` element.

Try removing that `<img>` tag, and using this for your CSS:

```
.main {
    background-image: url(b.png);
}

.main:hover {
    background-image: url(c.png);
}
```

You probably also need to give `.main` a height and width, since it no longer has anything inside it to give it a size.

Comment: But: this is bad for accessibilty, search-engines etc., if the image is content and not only decoration.

Comment: @unor: A good point, certainly. Unfortunately, the only way I know for switching an `<img>`'s `src` is with JavaScript. I suppose you could have two images, one of which is always hidden... would that really be better though?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with what you are doing, except that the image(b.png) is of course on top of the background...So you can't see the background image.